# Creating a Feeds Plugin Child from a custom module and calling the new method

Tags: 7, feeds, plugins

I’ve got a module where I need to overwrite a method from another Feeds Plugins class. To do this I’ve followed [the developer's guide to Feeds](https://www.drupal.org/node/622700).

So I have implemented hook_feeds_plugins and hook_enable. These are being reached fine. The aim of my new child class is to override the parse method in  FeedsCSVParser

In my code I have this line:

```
$result = $this->importer->parser->parse($this, $result);
```

This still runs through the parent class and not the child one I’ve created.  How do I tell my Module to use the new parse method instead?

When i break point this line I can see in `$this->importer->parser->pluginDefinition` that this array should probably be of the new info I've entered in `hook_feeds_plugins`, but is showing that previous class instead.

Thanks for any guidance that can be given.

Answer (score 0):

I have the issue fixed however this may not be the best method.  If you know what is then please let me know.

You can set a Plugin with 'setPlugin'

```
$this->importer->setPlugin('PreviewFeedsParser');
```

This wipes the config though.  So the following code shows - getting the config, setting the plugin and readding the config.

```
$this->importer->setPlugin('PreviewFeedsParser');
$this->importer->parser->setConfig($config);
$result = $this->importer->parser->parse($this, $result);
```